# why asp.net shows different version numbers

Tags: asp.net

Why does the header X-aspnet-version in ASP.NET show different version? According to asp.net error page 's version they show different versions from each other.

Appreciate Y'all.

Comment: Post an example if you may

Comment: Are you redirecting to a different web application perhaps? It's impossible to answer without *any* information. Different versions though most likely means different application pools

Comment: Sorry for late response  example screenshots  [link](http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vbl8cy&s=9#.V2ugKitvavk) [link](https://postimg.org/image/i1j4yxclj/)